# ReferenceError: gapi is not defined

Tags: javascript

```
src="https://plus.google.com/js/client.js"
var apiKey = 'AIzaSyAjUssjwrNAfvCTb0thDlCoRqMibyEB0Ow';
gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
var longurl = 'http://www.google.com/';

gapi.client.load('urlshortener', 'v1', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.urlshortener.url.insert({
        'resource': {
            'longUrl': longurl
        }
    });
    var resp = request.execute(function(resp) {
        if (resp.error) {
            $("#show").html('Error. ' + resp.error.message);
        } else {
            $("#show").html("Short URL for "+longurl+" is: " + resp.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Пробовал подключать разные библиотеки

Answer (score 1):

Используйте:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=OnLoadCallback"></script>
```

Источник: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/